# PowerShell Get-Content do not display currency symbol euro (€), pound (£)

Tags: powershell, encoding, euro, pound

I read a csv file that contains currency symbol : us dollar ($), british pound (£) and euro (€).
Here a short extract:

```
337;European €;NULL;
426;British £;NULL;
337;Americain $;NULL;
```

I use a powershell command to replace the "NULL" literal string in the file by an empty string :

```
(Get-Content %OutputFile%) -replace 'NULL', '' | Out-File -encoding unicode %OutputFile%
```

But the Get-Content don't correctly read the currencies symbols and return this :

```
337;ODEYEUREU;hf;Odey European â‚¬;;
426;INFLECGB;hf;Inflection Point C Â£;;
337;ODEYEUREU;hf;Odey European $;;
```

If the dollar is OK, the pound is prefixed by an expected character and the euro symbol is not display.

What encoding to use to handle all currency symbols (that I can specify in a inline command) ?

Comment: I launched a powershell command from a batch file to replace the string "NULL". Because I've not found the DOS equivalent. And I can't rewrite the full batch to ps file.

Comment: Try `(Get-Content %OutputFile% -Encoding utf8) -replace 'NULL', ' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `UTF8` encoding on both the `Get-Content` side and the `Out-File` side otherwise it might infer (guess) that you are trying to read in `ASCII` content. Otherwise the `Out-File` will take the mis-encoded content and output it "wrong". Try this:

```
(Get-Content %OutputFile% -Encoding UTF8) -replace 'NULL', '' | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 %OutputFile%
```

Comment: Nice, but note that `Get-Content` in Windows PowerShell assumes the system's _ANSI_ code page in the absence of a BOM, not _ASCII_. By contrast, in PowerShell (Core) 7+ UTF-8 is now the consistent default, across all cmdlets, and - unlike in Windows PowerShell with `-Encoding utf8` - a BOM-_less_ UTF-8 file is created by default (use `-Encoding utf8BOM` if you need one).